# Configure an interface with no IP

Tags: 18.04, ip, interface, netplan

I need to configure an interface so that it has no IP on 18.04 with Netplan.

Right now with dhcp4 set as false it's forcing the interface into a down state.

How can I do this without changing back to ifupdown?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this, other than using `networkd-dispatcher`.  But... for context, what are you using the interface for that you care about its state only?

Comment: The box has 2 NICs, one for management and the other to sniff traffic with tshark. I ended up putting in "ip link set dev eth2 up" in the rc.local file.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's a native way to do this in Netplan. I ended up putting "ip link set dev eth2 up" in the rc.local file.

Comment: I also ended up resorting to this.  some of my machines picked up a V6 address which worked too.  Like #mono I use this for network monitoring ports